Why Entrez esearch doesn't provide all abstracts from PubMed?
I'm trying to fetch abstracts from PubMed using Entrez (Biopython). In the code, I collect the data with Entrez.esearch and Entrez.efetch, write it to the file and then get needed info to the DataFrame. There's a condition in esearch to get articles just with abstract ('... AND has abstract[FILT]').
Here is the code:
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline
import datetime
import pandas as pd

Entrez.email = 'example@example.com'
search_results = Entrez.read(
    Entrez.esearch(
        db="pubmed", term='Autism AND has abstract[FILT]', mindate = '2012/12/31',  maxdate = '3000/12/12', usehistory="y"
    )
)

count = int(search_results["Count"])
print("Found %i results" % count)

webEnv = search_results["WebEnv"]
queryKey = search_results["QueryKey"]
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", retmode="text", rettype='medline', webenv=webEnv, query_key=queryKey)
data = handle.read()

with open('./abstracts_medline.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(data)

# convert in dataframes
pmids = []
years = []
months = []
days = []
titles = []
abstracts = []

with open('./abstracts_medline.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    medline_rec = Medline.parse(f)
    for record in medline_rec:
        if('AB' in record.keys()):
            pmids.append(record['PMID'])
            try:
                years.append(int(record['PHST'][-1].split('/')[0]))
                months.append(int(record['PHST'][-1].split('/')[1]))
                days.append(int(record['PHST'][-1].split('/')[2].split(' ')[0]))
            except KeyError:
                years.append(None)
                months.append(None)
                days.append(None)
            try:
                titles.append(record['TI'])
            except KeyError:
                titles.append(None)
            abstracts.append(record['AB'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'PMID': pmids,
        'Year': years,
        'Month': months,
        'Day': days,
        'Title': titles,
        'Abstract': abstracts
    }
)

# filter for NA
df = df.dropna()
# change format
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(int)
df['Day'] = df['Day'].astype(int)

count = df.shape[0]
print("Fetched %i available abstracts" % count)

docs = list(df['Abstract'])
timestamps = [datetime.date(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(df['Year'], df['Month'], df['Day'])]
print('Read %i abstracts' % len(timestamps))

I get the next results:
Found 55574 results
Fetched 9946 available abstracts
Read 9946 abstracts

I expected to get the same or at least close to the number of fetched available abstracts as the number of results found, but I got just about 20%. Where could be the problem?

I found that there can be a problem with the maximum volume of request (it seems to be 10000). I tried to use retstart and retmax in efetch but couldn’t find proper instructions so it didn’t work
